# Use pdist2() to return an index of second smallest value in matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to use `pdist2` to return the indexes of the second smallest values instead of the values themselves. So for example:

```
% Compute the ordinary Euclidean distance
X = randn(100, 5);
Y = randn(25, 5);
D = pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean', 'smallest', 2); % euclidean distance
```

How would I change `pdist2` so that `D` contains indices and not values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a second return argument:

```
X = randn(100, 5);
Y = randn(25, 5);
[D I] = pdist2(X,Y,'euclidean', 'smallest', 2); % euclidean distance
```

`I` will contain the index. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html